# Problem simplifying the following expression

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am using the library Sympy, this is the code:

```
import sympy as sp
β, t, t1=sy.symbols("β t t+1")
((β**t1)/(β**t)).simplify()
```

What I want to get is:

```
β
```

but what I am receiving is:

```
β**(−++1)
```

You can see that the code is not subtracting the ts, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symbolic expression is composed of many entities. To name a few, symbols (which are the most basic ones), numbers, functions, operators, ...

A symbol can get an arbitrary name. So, with this command:

```
β, t, t1=sp.symbols("β t t+1")
```

you created 3 symbols. `t1` will be rendered on the screen with `t+1`. However, `t1` is a symbol just like `β` and `t`. `t1` is not a symbolic expression! You need to declare `t1` as a symbolic expression:

```py
import sympy as sp
β, t = sp.symbols("β t")
t1 = t + 1
((β**t1)/(β**t)).simplify()
# out: β
```